# Order of redirection and process substitution

Tags: bash, io-redirection, process-substitution

What is the process order of redirection and process substitution?
One line command to process pre error works Ok.

```
{ echo hello;jiji jio; } 2> >(while read line;do echo "____$line";done) >right.log
```

While this order does not.

```
{ echo hello;jiji jio; } >right.log 2> >(while read line;do echo "____$line";done)
```

Comment: Maybe it would be useful if you revealed what you *think* those commands should do, as well as what they actually do on the shell you use (presumably bash, given the tag). Also, just in case, the bash version could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @rici. 
I use bash 5.1. I just want to process the error of the pre command group in the subshell. First case gives what I have expected. Print the error process result and others to a file, while the second case print all to the file.

Comment: In the second case, the subshell hasn't yet been created when you redirect stdout. So it picks up that redirection. In the first case, it's created before the redirection, so it doesn't. I hope the answer is clear about that.

Comment: Thanks for your reminding to improve my questioning skills. @rici

Comment: Yes, I got it now. The explanation you've made is very clear, very nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ { echo hello;jiji jio; } 2> >(while read line;do echo "____$line";done) >right.log
____jiji: command not found
$ cat right.log 
hello
```

In the above, it is like `jiji jio 2>&1 | while read line;do echo "____$line";done` and `echo hello >right.log`.

```
$ { echo hello;jiji jio; } >right.log 2> >(while read line;do echo "____$line";done)
$ cat right.log 
hello
____jiji: command not found
```

In the second, it is like `{ echo hello; jiji jio 2>&1 | while read line;do echo "____$line";done } >right.log`. Remember that `echo "____$line"` portion triggers it to be redirected to `>right.log` (because it writes to stdout).

So yes, order does matter. In the second case `>right.log` redirection is *remembered* when processing `2> >(...)` and whenever `...` writes to stdout it is redirected to `>right.log`.

Answer (score 3):

Redirections are processed left-to-right. That's certainly what Posix says: (Near the end of [the prologue to section 2.7](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07))

> If more than one redirection operator is specified with a command, the order of evaluation is from beginning to end.

And the bash manual (v5.1) agrees:

> Redirections are processed in the order they appear, from left to right. ([Section 3.6](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections))

So in the first case, when the `>(...)` subprocess is created, stdout has not yet been redirected, and so the original stdout is inherited by the subprocess, and that's where it sends its output (the line it read from the `{...}`'s stderr).

In the second case, stdout is redirected to `right.log` before the subprocess is created, so that's what the subprocess inherits as its stdout, and thus where it will echo its input. Thus, `right.log` ends up with both the line echoed by the main process and the error redirected into the subprocess and then echoed with leading underscores.

That seems to be the behaviour of bash 4.4 and bash 5.0, which are what I have handy.

Note, however, that redirection to a pipeline happens *before* any redirections in the command, even though the pipe operator is further to the right:

> The standard input, standard output, or both of a command shall be considered to be assigned by the pipeline before any redirection specified by redirection operators that are part of the command. ([Posix section 2.9.2](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02)).

That didn't seem relevant to this question, but it might be useful to know.